# Java: return statement compilation error

Tags: java, if-statement, syntax, compilation, compiler-errors

I have wrote the following code in Java, but there is an error saying "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: "

```
    public static int guessNum (int num){
        if (num == 0){
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }

        if (num > 0){
            return 1;
        }

        if (num < 0){
            return 0;
        }
    }
```

When I changed the last `if` statement to `else{return 0;}`, the error disappeared.

I wonder if there a way to keep the last if statement as `if()` rather than `else{}`, since I think the former is more readable.

EDIT:
Suppose I am running this method in a main method:

```
public static void main (String[] args){
    System.out.println(guessNum(10));
}
```

The error occurred:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
>       This method must return a result of type int

Comment: Show us the exact error.

Comment: The last if is unnecessary - as well as an else. See my answer for details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting the error because your method returns an 'int'.
All of your return statements are contained within 'if' conditions. The compiler will complain that it is possible that none of your conditions will be satisfied (even though they are - you are checking for all cases).

You need to provide a default return statement. In fact, the last if is unnecessary because if the num is != 0 and not > 0 then it must be < 0.

Change the method to:

```
public static int guessNum (int num){
    if (num == 0){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }

    if (num > 0){
        return 1;
    }

    return 0; //The other conditions were not met so this must be the result
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It could be because your method is expected to return an integer value but using only if-statement does not guarantee that a integer will be returned. So use the following, which should solve the issue:

```
public static int guessNum (int num){
    if (num == 0){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    } else if (num > 0){
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The Java compiler sees that, if none of the three conditions is met (despite this being impossible), there is no `return` statement. A possible fix is to add the following line below the `if`s:

```
throw new AssertionError("Impossible to reach.");
```

An [`AssertionError`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/AssertionError.html) should be thrown to indicate that an assertion has failed, including when an impossible condition has been satisfied. It also terminates the method in the impossible case that none of the `if`s are `true`, which satisfies the compiler.